# Best way to handle multiple event listeners

Tags: android, android-event

Let's say I have a spinner(with 2 items) and a radiogroup (with 2 radiobuttons).

I want to show for example a TextView in my layout which will be with different values for every choice:

For example we have:

#### Spinner

Male
Female

#### RadioGroup

True False

#### So we have 4 cases:

1. Male True
2. Female False
3. Male False
4. Female True

In short, each time user selects any of these choices, I want to show a different textview.
I have placed event listeners on spinners and radiobuttons:

#### Spinner Listener

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            ``// TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
```

#### Radio Group Listener

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                          //switch checkedId and check which spinner item is selected...
                          //then show the textview
                     }
```

But this sometimes works sometimes not- I am having many and different problems.
I also tried similar choices. But nothing worked preperly.

How can dynamically handle this **without** adding an extra button?

Comment: Create a method you will call in both of these listeners, then check the values of both to determine what views to show.

Comment: @LarryMcKenzie McKenzie I am not sure that I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this better explains my comment.

```
int selectedSpinnerItem = -1;
int selectedRadioGroupItem = -1;

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        selectedSpinnerItem = position;
        updateViews();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        selectedSpinnerItem = -1;
        updateViews();
    }
});

radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        selectedRadioGroupItem = checkedId;
        updateViews();
    }
});

public void updateViews(){
    // Here is where you will compare the values 
    // and display the appropriate views.
}
```

Comment: I have tried something similar with variables. I will try your solution and come back later to accept/upvote the answer.

Comment: If this does not work please update your question to show me how you implemented it.

Comment: Absolutely! Thank you

Comment: I don t know if this is the best practice/efficient way, but your logic is simple and works perfect. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create all TextViews you want..

Than just change their visibilty..

```
TextView v = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
v.setVisibility(View.GONE); // Or view.VISIBLE, View.INVISIBLE
```

So you can visible the specific text view you want according to your logic.
Or you can just create 2 textViews.. One will be for Male/Female and one for True/False;

I think the better thing to do is just change the text in on general textView.. But i am not sure what is the problem because i don't have code example that can help me understand

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you but this is not my problem. The problem is that I can not find a reliable way to know which spinner item was selected and which radio button at the same time. Not how will I change the textviews.

Comment: Sorry but i am not sure i understand.. What the method spinner.getSelectedItem() and the same for radionButton.
This link might help: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-radio-buttons-example/
If you can explain and add you code parts i will be able to help more